# Which permissions are actually needed to update a user alias in Google Directory API?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-workspace

I am attempting to manage email aliases with a user I set up in the Google Directory console, but am running into a surprising permission issue.

I have created an admin role within the google directory console that has two API privileges: Read users, and Add/Remove aliases:

[image: admin api privileges in google admin]

Below is code that I have written to manage the aliases. I should note that this code is known to work for a super-admin account; it's only on this account with more limited permissions that it's not working.

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'

const apiUser = 'myAPIUser@domain.com'
const targetAlias = 'myAlias@dmain.com'

const directoryAuth = new google.auth.JWT(
client_email,
undefined,
private_key,
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias'],
apiUser
);
const service = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth:directoryAuth});

// Get current aliases -- this part works
const getUserResponse = await service.users.get({
    userKey:apiUser
});
const currentAliases = getUserResponse.data.aliases


// Add aliases: - returns 403 with message "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
await service.users.aliases.insert({
    userKey:apiUser,
    requestBody:{
        alias: targetAlias
    }
});
```

The code above fails on the last line when it attempts to insert, returning:

```
  code: 403,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Not Authorized to access this resource/api',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'forbidden'
    }
  ]
```

According to the Method: users.aliases.insert [docs here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users.aliases/insert), the alias endpoint needs one of three permissions:

```
Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:

 1. https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/
 2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
 3. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias
```

Is there a different set of API privileges I should be checking to satisfy the roles above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kind of unsatisfying answer, but I believe there must have just been a delay in applying the permissions on the Google API side, because it started working within an hour.

So it is possible that if you are sure you have the correct permissions, just try waiting a few minutes for those permissions to be fully applied.